# What kind of software testing is Selenium 2.0?

Tags: java, selenium

I just what to know your opinion about this.
We all know that Selenium is a Black Box Testing, but it is a Unitng Testing or an Intergration Testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically integrating testing.

I think that pure unit test is a test that verifies as smaller unit as you can separate. In java the smaller unit is class. Therefore theoretically unit test is a test that deals with one class.

In fact this is not always correct and sometimes unit tests deal with several classes and even "modules", so they are almost integration tests.

In theory integration tests deal with whole application or module. But what is module? 10 classes? 100 classes? Web application? Several enterprise applications working together?

Usually once we run our application into container and test it this test is called integration test. This is what selenium does. However it depends on your point of view. For example the typical configuration is when web application is deployed on Tomcat + MySQL on production and running with jetty + hsqldb via maven during testing. The maven phase that runs application in jetty is called "integration-tests". Probably at this phase you's like to use selenium.

But QA will say that the "real" integration testing is a testing against real deployment with tomcat and mysql.

Comment: I see thank for clearing that up for me. :D

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be Functional Testing?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_testing